# eclipse not starting in Windows 10

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Juno on windows 10 machine, It was working fine till now, I performed Disk Cleanup for C drive (Deleting all System logs, temporary files.. etc ) after Restarting the System ,I was not able to open Eclipse. after clicking on eclipse icon the screen appears and disappears soon.

Earlier also i have performed such Disk Cleanup activity but never faced such problem.
Please Help me in fixing the problem.

Comment: You're using a version of Eclipse that is 5 versions old?

Comment: though it's too old, but I believe it should not stop working in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Eclipse in `clean` mode.
Right click on the Eclipse Juno execution icon on the desktop/folder, go to `properties` and add `-clean` to the end of the `Target` path.

For example:
`C:\eclipse-juno\eclipse.exe -clean`.

After a successful (and slow) launch, remove the `-clean` from the path.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a configuration issue in Eclipse.

Open eclipse.ini, try to increase the memory:

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```